# Cross Domain RSS feed - causing 500 internal server error and unexpected token <

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, rss

I'm trying to display a wordpress RSS feed on another site using DOMDocument in PHP. theres been no change to the RSS from the standard Wordpress layout.  The code I'm using to pull it in is as follows:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://www.wchg.org.uk/news/feed/');
```

with that it causes a **500 Internal Server Error**.  The whole page just fails to load.

I tried to access the feed via jQuery Ajax calls instead

```
jQuery.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:"http://www.wchg.org.uk/news/feed/",
dataType:'json',
async:false,
crossDomain: true,
success : function(data){
    alert(data);},
error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
    alert(status+" "+exception);
}
})
```

With that, I got errors stating that No **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** was set. I tried setting the dataType to jsonp and I then got **Syntax Error Unexpected Token <** instead

So then I finally added **header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");** to the top of the index.php file for the entire site, This then made json and jsonp dataTypes give the same error of unexpected Token <.

I cant seem to work out how best to fix this and whats even causing it.  Its only started happening since we had moved from goDaddy to another hosting service.

All suggestions welcome!!

Comment: tried with dataType:'jsonp' ?

Comment: Why you don't use CURL function to get the data ?

Comment: Forget the ajax approach, xml is not jsonp. Turn on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);` then you will see why `$rss-load()` fails

Comment: Error reporting wouldnt display anything at all. not sure what was causing it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Solved 
I was using it to build up a newsticker taking the feed from another site, Ended up scraping the PHP route and built the jQuery as php was building the page.  Seems to work now.  Still no idea what caused the internal server error

```
$list = '
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
           url: \'http://www.wchg.org.uk/news/feed/\',
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "xml",
           success: function (result) {
                jQuery(result).find(\'item\').each(function () {
                    jQuery(".ticker").append("<li class=\"news-item\"><a href=\""+jQuery(this).find(\'link\').text()+"\" title=\""+jQuery(this).find(\'title\').text()+"\">"+jQuery(this).find(\'title\').text()+"</a></li>");
                 });                     
               }
           }).done( function() {
                jQuery("#cbnewsticker'.$id.'").ticker({
                controls: false,
                displayType: "reveal",
            });
           });




    });     
</script>
```

Comment: turns out this throws us another error, as this solution doesnt work in IE9 or below!!